Js relationship tree family Tree Parent Identification based on Group Names
I created the following code that allows me to create a relationship tree.
But I'm having the following problem if a user in his group name contains the fullname of another user then he is a child of him.
Example:

Users with the group: "Song Ki-Baek's Family" are children of the user with fullname: "Song Ki-Baek"
Users with the group: "On Woo-Joo's Family" are children of the user with fullname: "On Woo-Joo"
Users with the group: "Song Ki-Baek's Grou" are children of the user with fullname: "Song Ki-Baek"
Users with group: "On Woo-Joo's Family" are children of the user with fullname: "JBC: On Woo-Joo's Team"
etc...

Can you give me a hand?



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Family Tree</title>
    <style>
        .tree ul {
            padding-top: 20px;
            position: relative;
            transition: all 0.5s;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
            -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
        }

        .tree li {
            float: left;
            text-align: center;
            list-style-type: none;
            position: relative;
            padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
            transition: all 0.5s;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
            -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
        }

        .tree li::before,
        .tree li::after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 50%;
            border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
            width: 50%;
            height: 20px;
        }

        .tree li::after {
            right: auto;
            left: 50%;
            border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
        }

        .tree li:only-child::after,
        .tree li:only-child::before {
            display: none;
        }

        .tree li:only-child {
            padding-top: 0;
        }

        .tree li:first-child::before,
        .tree li:last-child::after {
            border: 0 none;
        }

        .tree li:last-child::before {
            border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
        }

        .tree li:first-child::after {
            border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
        }

        .tree ul ul::before {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 50%;
            border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
            width: 0;
            height: 20px;
        }

        .tree li a {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #666;
            font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
            font-size: 11px;
            display: inline-block;
            border-radius: 5px;
            transition: all 0.5s;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
            -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
        }

        .tree li a:hover,
        .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
            background: #c8e4f8;
            color: #000;
            border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
        }

        .tree li a:hover+ul li::after,
        .tree li a:hover+ul li::before,
        .tree li a:hover+ul::before,
        .tree li a:hover+ul ul::before {
            border-color: #94a0b4;
        }

        img {
            background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png");
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="tree" id="tree"></div>
    <script>
        const data = [
            { surname: "Song", name: "Ki-Baek", fullname: "Song Ki-Baek", group: "Cast", photo: "https://asianwiki.com/images/c/cd/Frankly_Speaking-Ko_Kyoung-Pyo.jpg" },
            { surname: "On", name: "Woo-Joo", fullname: "On Woo-Joo", group: "Cast", photo: "https://asianwiki.com/images/c/c6/Frankly_Speaking-Kang_Han_Na.jpg" },
            { surname: "Kim", name: "Jeong-Heon", fullname: "Kim Jeong-Heon", group: "Cast", photo: "https://asianwiki.com/images/0/08/Frankly_Speaking-Joo_Jong-Hyuk.jpg" },
            { surname: "Song", name: "In-Soo", fullname: "Song In-Soo", group: "Song Ki-Baek's Family", photo: "https://asianwiki.com/images/7/72/Frankly_Speaking-Shin_Jung_Keun1.jpg" },
            { surname: "Na", name: "Yoo-Jung", fullname: "Na Yoo-Jung", group: "Song Ki-Baek's Family", photo: "https://asianwiki.com/images/5/51/Frankly_Speaking-Kang_Ae_Shim.jpg" },
            { surname: "Song", name: "Un-Baek", fullname: "Song Un-Baek", group: "Song Ki-Baek's Family", photo: "https://asianwiki.com/images/a/a4/Frankly_Speaking-Hwang_Sung-Bin.jpg" },
            { surname: "Song", name: "Poong-Baek", fullname: "Song Poong-Baek", group: "Song Ki-Baek's Family", photo: "https://asianwiki.com/images/2/27/Frankly_Speaking-Lee_Jin-Hyuk.jpg" },
            { surname: "On", name: "Bok-Ja", fullname: "On Bok-Ja", group: "On Woo-Joo's Family", photo: "https://asianwiki.com/images/9/92/Frankly_Speaking-Baek_Joo-Hee1.jpg" },
            { surname: "Jung", name: "Gu-Won", fullname: "Jung Gu-Won", group: "On Woo-Joo's Family", photo: "https://asianwiki.com/images/1/10/Frankly_Speaking-Park_Jae_Joon.jpg" },
            { surname: "Yoon", name: "Ji-Hoo", fullname: "Yoon Ji-Hoo", group: "Song Ki-Baek's Group", photo: "https://asianwiki.com/images/d/d3/Frankly_Speaking-Ko_Kyu-Pil.jpg" },
            { surname: "", name: "Sung-Jin", fullname: "Sung-Jin", group: "Song Ki-Baek's Group", photo: "https://asianwiki.com/images/0/01/Frankly_Speaking-Han_Kyu-Won1.jpg" },
            { surname: "Chae", name: "Yeon", fullname: "Chae Yeon", group: "JBC: On Woo-Joo's Team", photo: "https://asianwiki.com/images/6/69/Frankly_Speaking-Kim_Sae-Byuk.jpg" },
            { surname: "Lee", name: "Ha-Young", fullname: "Lee Ha-Young", group: "JBC: On Woo-Joo's Team", photo: "https://asianwiki.com/images/1/1b/Frankly_Speaking-Lee_Bom_Sori.jpg" },
            { surname: "Lee", name: "Min-Gu", fullname: "Lee Min-Gu", group: "JBC: On Woo-Joo's Team", photo: "https://asianwiki.com/images/a/a2/Frankly_Speaking-Lee_Min-Goo.jpg" },
            { surname: "Sung", name: "I-Na", fullname: "Sung I-Na", group: "JBC: On Woo-Joo's Team", photo: "https://asianwiki.com/images/b/b9/Frankly_Speaking-Patricia_Yiombi1.jpg" },
            { surname: "Kim", name: "Sang-Jin", fullname: "Kim Sang-Jin", group: "JBC", photo: "https://asianwiki.com/images/a/ab/Frankly_Speaking-Jo_Han-Chul.jpg" },
            { surname: "Lee", name: "Hye-Yeon", fullname: "Lee Hye-Yeon", group: "JBC", photo: "https://asianwiki.com/images/7/70/Frankly_Speaking-Hong_Bi_Ra.jpg" },
        ];

        function createFamilyTree(data) {
            const tree = {};

            data.forEach(person => {
                const group = person.group;
                if (!tree[group]) {
                    tree[group] = [];
                }
                tree[group].push(person);
            });

            return tree;
        }

        function createTreeElement(tree) {
            const ul = document.createElement('ul');

            for (const group in tree) {
                const li = document.createElement('li');
                li.innerHTML = `<a href="#">${group}</a>`;

                const subUl = document.createElement('ul');
                tree[group].forEach(person => {
                    const subLi = document.createElement('li');
                    subLi.innerHTML = `<a href="#"><img src="${person.photo}" alt="" width="50" height="50" style="  border-radius: 50%;"><br>
         ${person.surname} ${person.name}</a>`;
                    subUl.appendChild(subLi);
                });

                li.appendChild(subUl);
                ul.appendChild(li);
            }

            return ul;
        }

        const familyTree = createFamilyTree(data);
        document.getElementById('tree').appendChild(createTreeElement(familyTree));
    </script>
</body>
</html>




"But I'm having the following problem": what then follows is not a problem description, but a description of some rules about child-parent relationships. What is the problem?

what is the desired tree object?
